# How can I make my own Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, fun

For some reason, I'm having difficulty remembering. I've got a photo of the ingredients, but some advice on exactly how to combine them would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Damn you and your misleading title! Got my duplicate gun all ready and everything

Comment: I take a `Rainbows and Unicorns` when you have the exact quantity of incredients. :)

Comment: @RichardTingle Misleading titles are the best titles.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [cooking.se].

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi While normal Cocktailcrafting questions would belong on Seasoned Advice, this question can only really be answered by employees of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Good grief that sounds saccharine!

Comment: Whatever gave you the impression that people in the UK start drinking as late as 5 @LowerClassOverflowian :-)?

Comment: Is this a menu from [Stack Exchange kitchen](http://www.businessinsider.com.au/stack-exchange-kitchen-tour-2014-2#welcome-to-the-stack-exchange-kitchen-in-new-yorks-financial-district-1)?

Comment: Be sure to be thorough in your unit testing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*The Stack Overflow* is just the classic *[Orange Blossom](http://cocktails.about.com/od/cocktailrecipes/r/orange_blossom.htm)* with a Maraschino cherry for garnish. This recipe calls for equal parts of each ingredient. For a standard cocktail, that would be:

> **Prep Time:** 3 minutes
> **Total Time:** 3 minutes
> **Yield:** 1 Cocktail
>
> #### Ingredients:
>
> - 3/4 ounce gin
> - 3/4 ounce sweet vermouth
> - 3/4 ounce orange juice
> - 1 Maraschino cherry
>
> #### Preparation:
>
> 1. Pour the ingredients into a mixing glass with ice cubes.
> 2. Stir well.
> 3. Strain into a chilled cocktail glass.
> 4. Add Maraschino cherry.

Cheers!

[image: Orange Blossom]

<sub><sup>*Photo via [Orange Blossom](http://cocktails.about.com/od/cocktailrecipes/r/orange_blossom.htm), Credit: © Colleen Graham*</sup></sub>

Comment: Please note that my "Cheers" should not be considered a salutation. It is a suggestion.

Comment: Surely you should have written this in Chef :-)?

Answer (score 65):

- For each shot of Orange Juice add 1 shot of gin
- For each shot of gin add 1 shot of Sweet vermouth.
- For each shot of sweet vermouth add 1 Maraschino cherry.
- For each Maraschino cherry add one shot of Orange Juice.

Comment: I hope I don't come across you at a cocktail bar.

Comment: It seems the _recursion_ was inevitable.

Comment: Somewhere in there should be "Drink half of what you have so far".

Comment: What is the side effect of this?

Comment: @rene universe crashing, no big deal

Comment: @rene Regret Overflow.

Comment: @rene Glass overflow.

Comment: @rene Hang Overflow...

Comment: @rene Life overflow...

Comment: +++ OUT OF GIN ERROR. REINSTALL UNIVERSE AND REBOOT +++

Comment: @TRiG, I'm surprised your system still runs on gin. We have diesel now.

Answer (score 10):

It's simple: In order to create your own "Stack Overflow" cocktail, you have to create your own "Stack Overflow" cocktail!

Comment: If you're having trouble with this, you might try reading [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224578/188613) for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
  class Program
  {
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        return MixItUp();
    }

    private static int MixItUp()
    {
        return AddOneShotOfGin();
    }

    private static int AddOneShotOfGin()
    {
        return AddOneShotOfSweetVermouth();
    }

    private static int AddOneShotOfSweetVermouth()
    {
        return AddOrangeJuiceAsYouPlease();
    }

    private static int AddOrangeJuiceAsYouPlease()
    {
        return AddAtLeastOneMaraschinoCherry();
    }

    private static int AddAtLeastOneMaraschinoCherry()
    {
        return MixItUp();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No proportions specified.  Achievement not unlocked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Lol. Added the portions now.